# Scheduled websocket push with Springboot

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-boot, push-notification

I want to create a simple news feed feature on the front end that will automatically update through websocket push notifications.

The technologies involved are:

- Angular for the general front-end application
- SockJS for creating websocket communication
- Stomp over webosocket for receiving messages from a message broker
- Springboot Websockets
- Stomp Message Broker (the java related framework)

What I want to achieve on the front end is:

1. Create a websocket connection when the view is loaded
2. Create s stomp provider using that websocket
3. Have my client subscribe to it
4. Catch server pushed messages and update the angular view

As far as the server side code:

1. Configure the websocket stuff and manage the connection
2. Have the server push messages every X amount of time (through an executor or `@Scheduled`?).

I think I have achieved everything so far except the last part of the server side code. The example I was following uses the websocket in full duplex mode and when a client sends something then the server immediately responds to the message queue and all subscribed clients update. But what I want is for the server itself to send something over `Stomp` WITHOUT waiting for the client to make any requests.

At first I created a spring `@Controller` and added a method to it with `@SendTo("/my/subscribed/path")` annotation. However I have no idea how to trigger it. Also I tried adding `@Scheduled` but this annotation works only on methods with `void` return type (and I'm returning a NewsMessage object).

Essentially what I need is to have the client initialize a websocket connection, and after have the server start pushing messages through it at a set interval (or whenever an event is triggered it doesn't matter for now). Also, every new client should listen to the same message queue and receive the same messages.

Comment: Do you have maybe a solition on Github ?

Comment: You can start from this simplified section by Spring framework :: [Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Before starting, make sure that you have the websocket dependencies in your `pom.xml`.  For instance, the most important one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, you need to have your configuration in place. I suggest you start with simple broker.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }

}
```

Then your controller should look like this. When your `AngularJs` app opens a connection on `/portfolio` and sends a subscription to channel `/topic/greeting`, you will reach the controller and respond to all subscribed users.

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    
    @MessageMapping("/greeting")
    public String handle(String greeting) {
        return "[" + getTimestamp() + ": " + greeting;
    }
}
```

With regard to your scheduler question, you need to enable it via configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig{}
```

And then schedule it:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledUpdatesOnTopic{

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    private final MessagesSupplier messagesSupplier;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=300)
    public void publishUpdates(){
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", messagesSupplier.get());
    }
}
```

Hope this somehow clarified the concept and steps to be taken to make things work for you.

Comment: shouldn't /topic/greeting mentioned in this part "send subscription to this channel /topic/greeeting you will receive this in controller and respond to all subscribed users" actually be /app/greeting ?

Comment: Generally intention was to send `greetings` periodically to all but respond with `greeting` to one user once someone requested.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work anymore as methods annotated with`@Scheduled` do not take any parameters as input.

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo, this is very strange, I've checked API and looks like all should work. Please check things again on your site.

Comment: @RMachnik I just double checked. This exception is thrown: `IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'myMethod': Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled`.

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo you are right, let me update my post. `@Scheduled` does not accept any input. If you want to pass something you can always do it by some provider.

Comment: @RMachnik see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946096/spring-boot-websocket-how-do-i-know-when-a-client-has-unsubscribed/54948213#54948213

Comment: @RMachnik above code is not publishingupdates to the topic periodically. what can be wrong here . Do we have to connect SimpMessagingTemplate with the websocket config somehow ?

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with your code. My response shows just concept. To give you tip, please check what beans you have loaded into context.

Answer (score 10):

First of all you can't send (push) messages to clients without their subscriptions.

Secondly to send messages to all subscribers you should take a look to the `topic` abstraction side.

That is a fundamentals of STOMP.

I think you are fine with `@Scheduled`, but you just need to inject `SimpMessagingTemplate` to send messages to the STOMP broker for pushing afterwards.

Also see [Spring WebSockets XML configuration not providing brokerMessagingTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294525/spring-websockets-xml-configuration-not-providing-brokermessagingtemplate)

Comment: Although I used your answer (my project was already using a `SimpMessagingTemplate` for sending 'logout' messages which I thought of using after posting the question) I marked the other as correct because it might be more helpful to other people.