# Spring Boot WebSocket: How do I know when a Client has Unsubscribed?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I currently have a simple WebSocket with STOMP setup where a client connects to a topic (with an ID). The controller immediately responds with what was asked for, and a variable is set indicating what the client has subscribed to. A method, annotated with `@Scheduled`, now sends to the client what it has requested every few seconds.

The scheduled method does not do anything until the client has connected for the first time. However, after the first subscription it will continue publishing regardless of whether a client is subscribed or not.

```
@Controller
public class ServiceWebSocketController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceService serviceService;

    @Autowired
    WebSocketSessionController webSocketSessionController;

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    private Set<Long> services = new HashSet<>();

    @SubscribeMapping("/service/{serviceId}")
    public ServiceDTO subscribe(@DestinationVariable("serviceId") final Long serviceId) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Subscribed to Service with ID: " + serviceId);
        services.add(serviceId);
        return serviceService.getServiceWithProperties(serviceId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Service", "id", serviceId));
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
    public void service() throws SQLException {
        services.removeIf(serviceId -> !webSocketSessionController.hasSubscriptionTo("/topic/service/" + serviceId));

        // Publish specified Service data to each anonymously subscribed client.
        services.forEach(serviceId -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Publishing Service with ID: " + serviceId);
                // We don't use .convertAndSendToUser here, because all our clients are anonymous.
                simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/service/" + serviceId, serviceService.getServiceWithProperties(serviceId));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**How can I tell if the client has unsubscribed? If something similar to `@UnsubscribeMapping` exists, I could simply set the `currentSubscriptionServiceId` variable to `null` again, preventing the scheduled method to publish data continuously.**

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the STOMP support to tell you the correct approach, but I can say that the fact that you're storing *global state* (the ID) inside the shared controller indicates an overall design problem.

Comment: @chrylis You are absolutely right. I am a novice programmer who is just starting out with Spring/WebSockets, so I'm still learning. I ended up using a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>` to store which clients are subscribed to which services. Using @Bertrand Pestre's answer below I was able to achieve what I wanted :)

Comment: Glad that's helping. Note that that will store the state *forever* if you don't clean it out, so in a production system you'll usually do something like storing that information in Redis or a similar key-value backend that can expire records.

Comment: @chrylis I updated my answer to reflect your suggestions. I monitor Connections/Disconnections/Subscriptions/Unsubscriptions (using `ApplicationListener`s as suggested by Bertrand Pestre's answer below) to determine which clients are connected and subscribed to specific services. If a client unsubscribes/disconnects, I remove their subscriptions and stop publishing the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to the event `SessionUnsubscribeEvent` like this:

```
@Controller
public class SessionUnsubscribeListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionUnsubscribeEvent> {

   @Override
   public void onApplicationEvent(SessionUnsubscribeEvent event) {
       GenericMessage message = (GenericMessage) event.getMessage();

       String simpDestination = (String) message.getHeaders().get("simpDestination");

       if ("/topic/service".equals(simpDestination)) {
           // do stuff
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Unfortunately, message.getHeaders().get("simpDestination")` returns `null` when an `SessionUnsubscribeEvent` event occurs.

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo Well, at least the listener is working ! About the headers, maybe the data structure is a bit different. You could run this in debug and try to look into the `event` object to find the topic you want

Comment: I ended up going with a `ConcurrentMap<String, String>` which I called `subscriptions`. Whenever a client subscribes to a publication, I store the `subscriptionId` and the `simpDestination`. That way, when a client unsubscribes, I just delete the map entry based on the `subscriptionId` (which you do get from the `SessionUnsubscribeEvent`).